# Custom UITableViewCells overlapping?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have 5 types of Custom UITableViewCell . I am having numberofrows also correct. But when it comes to display. The last 2 cells are getting over each other . 
[This is the method i am using to display the cells for the indexpath row. every if statement is working properly. as i checked with NSlog in it .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNwVN.png)

[image]

```
 if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            TaskDetailTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TaskDetail" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        [cell.assignTo setText:@"  Lalu • Aug 30 , 2014  "];
        [cell.taskname setText:task_name];
        [cell.comments_countLbl setText:comments_count];
        // Configure the cell...
        NSLog(@"Cell Type %@",@"Task Detail");
        return cell;
    }

    else if (![comments[indexPath.row] isEqual:[NSNull null]] && ![imagecomments[indexPath.row] isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
        Image_Text_Commet_TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"image_text_comment" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell.commentText setText:[comments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSString *imageURL = [imagecomments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *convertURltoImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"http://localhost:3001/",imageURL];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:convertURltoImage];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        UIImage *placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"];

        __weak Image_Text_Commet_TableViewCell *weakCell = cell;

        [cell.imageComment setImageWithURLRequest:request
                              placeholderImage:placeholderImage
                                       success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

                                           weakCell.imageComment.image = image;
                                           [weakCell setNeedsLayout];

                                       } failure:nil];
        NSLog(@"Cell Type %@",@"Image and Text");

        return cell;

    }

    else if (![imagecomments[indexPath.row] isEqual:[NSNull null]] && [comments[indexPath.row] isEqual:[NSNull null]]){
        ImageCommentTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ImageComment" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSString *imageURL = [imagecomments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *convertURltoImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"http://localhost:3001/",imageURL];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:convertURltoImage];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        UIImage *placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder1"];

        __weak ImageCommentTableViewCell *weakCell = cell;

        [cell.imageComment setImageWithURLRequest:request
                                 placeholderImage:placeholderImage
                                          success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

                                              weakCell.imageComment.image = image;
                                              [weakCell setNeedsLayout];

                                          } failure:nil];
        NSLog(@"Cell Type %@",@"Image Only");


        return cell;
    }

    else if ([imagecomments[indexPath.row] isEqual:[NSNull null]] && ![comments[indexPath.row] isEqual:[NSNull null]]){
        CommentTaskTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"commentText" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell.memberComment setText:[comments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSLog(@"Cell Type %@",@"Text Only");

        return cell;
    }

    else {

        AddCommentTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Addcomment" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSLog(@"Cell Type %@",@"Add Task Only")![This is the method i am using to display the cells for the indexpath row. every if statement is working properly. as i checked with NSlog in it .][3];

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Make the height of the cell bigger ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the height of cell dynamically that may be the problem

use this method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  CGFloat rowHeight = [self getRowHeightForRow: indexPath.row];
  return rowHeight;
}
```

Comment: where is getRowHeightForRow method?

Comment: There is not such method, you need to calculate height on behalf of the custom cell that you are going to display or the content that you are going to display in that indexPath cell.

Comment: Their is a problem with height only . As i hard coded CGFloat. and it did worked .

Comment: Issue fixed , I missed to add constrains in View . Sorry . and thanks for help :) !!